# Laravel 5.2 and Cashier

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan, laravel-cashier

I have added:

```
"laravel/cashier": "^6.0"
```

to composer.json

and:

```
Laravel\Cashier\CashierServiceProvider::class,
```

to app.php in the providers array in the config folder.

I have then run composer update, but if I do:

```
php artisan
```

I do not see the cashier command there. Am I missing a step?

Comment: That is actually true, I have been on this myself, I do not see the artisan comman

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That command appears to be removed in 5.2. In looking at the [docs for 5.2](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/billing) they've been updated and there is no longer a reference to using the artisan helper `$php artisan cashier:table users

Rather is seems you must now create the migration manually rather than using a helper. From the docs:

Update the **user** table migration(or whichever entity you are associating with your billing):

```
Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
    $table->string('stripe_id')->nullable();
    $table->string('card_brand')->nullable();
    $table->string('card_last_four')->nullable();
});
```

Create a subscriptions table:

```
Schema::create('subscriptions', function ($table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('stripe_id');
    $table->string('stripe_plan');
    $table->integer('quantity');
    $table->timestamp('trial_ends_at')->nullable();
    $table->timestamp('ends_at')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Then run the migrate command `$ php artisan migrate`

I wasn't able to find any info on the reason for this change or whether they'll be re-introducing this artisan command in the future. I assume it is by design though.

[Click here for more info on creating migrations.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations)

Hope it helps!